# Checking phone numbers for equivalence

Tags: regex

What's the best way to check phone numbers in different formats for equivalence?

Different formats:

"(708) 399 7222"

"7083997222"

"708-399-7222"

"708399-7222"

"+1 (708) 399-7222"

"+1 (708)399-7222"

**Additional Difficulty:** what if the phone number isn't prefaced by the country code?

Comment: First remove all non-digit characters and then compare

Comment: @AmilWaduwawara ok what about 17083997222 vs 7083997222. These are the same number, but the country code in front throws it off...

Comment: In the general case, you cannot know if 7085551212 is equivalen to itself, or if one instance refers to a US phone number and another, say, to a UK number.

Comment: Any user interface which attempts to capture a number of phone numbers must make clear that it assumes a certain "local" code, possibly both an international country code and an "area" code within the country, such that any numbers which appear to be too short can be tested with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a single regular expression. To get a canonical representation that can be compared:

1. Replace an initial + with your [international call prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes). In many countries this is `00`.
2. If number doesn't start with the prefix, add the prefix and the country code for your country.
3. Remove all non-digits.

This will be sufficient if you only have to deal with calls made from a single country, for example if you are developing something for internal use at a phone company. If you have to accept a wide range of inputs from different countries with various prefixes I suggest finding a well tested library to do this.

Comment: 00 is not the foreign call code everywhere. Where I live, a US phone number would look like 990 1 708 555 1212. Most everyone will write that with a +1 these days, though.

Comment: Indeed. `+` is the **correct** prefix, inasmuch as it is internationally recognised by all telecoms providers and regulators around the world.

Comment: Thanks, I have experience only of countries where 00 is recognized as the prefix. Can you confirm that all phone operators everywhere translate + into the correct prefix? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes seems to suggest it's only for cell phone networks

Comment: It's not recognised or actioned by telecoms equipment, but the recognised format for writing numbers down (or storing them). Almost all recent mobile phones have had the ability to store a number with that prefix and then to use the correct international access code depending on where it is when you make a call. Land lines tend not to need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
 \(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}
```

Or:

```
^\+?(\d[\d-]+)?(\([\d-.]+\))?[\d-]+\d$
```

**[Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/J0gMiBPsVA)**

Comment: does this deal with the possibility that one version of the phone number includes the country code, but another version might not?

Comment: @Auser I have updated solution. please take a look at my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `PhoneEqualityComparer` class. If you deal only with US numbers, the following code will work:

```
sealed class PhoneEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Equals(NormalizePhone(x), NormalizePhone(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return NormalizePhone(obj).GetHashCode();
    }

    private static string NormalizePhone(string phone)
    {
        if (phone.StartsWith("+1"))
            phone = phone.Substring(2);
        return Regex.Replace(phone, @"\D", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
string[] phones = new[] {
    "(708) 399 7222",
    "7083997222",
    "708-399-7222",
    "708399-7222",
    "+1 (708) 399-7222",
    "+1 (708)399-7222"
};
string[] uniquePhones = phones.Distinct(new PhoneEqualityComparer()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty neat regex that will replace:

- any plus sign followed by one or more digits
- any character that is not a digit or a line break character

with a blank string

```
string text = Regex.Replace( inputString, @"\+\d+|[^0-9\r\n]", "" , RegexOptions.None | RegexOptions.Multiline );
```

**Input:**

```
"(708) 399 7222"
"7083997222"
"708-399-7222"
"708399-7222"
"+1 (708) 399-7222"
"+1 (708)399-7222"
```

**Output:**

```
7083997222
7083997222
7083997222
7083997222
7083997222
7083997222
```

Comment: This will discard everything if the country code is not separated from the rest of the number.

Comment: is the country code always one digit? Or is it always separated by a space or a bracket?  If there are more test inputs, they should be added to the test cases :)

Comment: Country codes can have up to 3 digits and can have a numeric prefix instead of `+`.

Comment: Tee hee, no, there are only nine countries in the world (-: